# Get and replace second last digit in integer -javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to increment the second last digit of the integer by 1. I used below code but always changing the last digit. Please help
For Example, I want to change 26925131 to 26925141.

```
function increment_last(v) {
    return v.replace(/[0-9]+(?!.*[0-9])/, function(match) {
       return parseInt(match, 10)+1;
    });
 }
```

Comment: what about `9` ? should it became zero?

Comment: so `return v+10;`?

Comment: yes 9 should come as Zero

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `10` instead `1`, and no need of regex match

```
  function increment_last(v) {
          return v+10;

     }
```

Comment: This will just add 10 to the number. Will not replace.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the second last digit for changing.

It works by looking for a character which is followed by another character and end of string (positive lookahead).

```js
function inc(number) {
    return +number.toString().replace(/.(?=.$)/, v => (+v + 1) % 10);
}

var value = 26925131;

console.log(inc(value));
```

Comment: Is this code in Javascript as it is not working for me. Where initialize number and v from?

Comment: `number` is the parameter from the function `inc`. it is initialised with the calling parameter or if not set, with `undefined`. `v` is a parameter of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is the match of the replacement function.